# Display images side by side php & css

Tags: php, html, css

Hey I have written some code to display pictures using php...However, the images are showing up as block and taking up the whole width of the screen when I would like to display them inline but with the words describing the books right below them. Can you please help me set this up
here is my code

```
for($row = 0; $row < sizeof($arr);$row++){
 echo '<img src="images/'.$arr[$row]['isbn'].'.jpg" alt="Mountain View" >'.$arr[$row]['title'].'<br/>by '.$arr[$row]['author'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="booktype" value="hardcover" >Hardcover: $'.$arr[$row]['hardcover'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="booktype" value="softcover" >Softcover: $'.$arr[$row]['softcover'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="booktype" value="e-book" >E-Book: $'.$arr[$row]['e-book'];
```

}

Again I would like the images to appear side by side not block...thank you..

okay I followed the code suggested for both of them the one that seemed to work was when I float everything left, but the words are appearing on the side when I do this..I have attached a picture..how can I fix this
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the source (`html`) to see how it is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add container div to contain each column or your images and give this div `display:inline-block;`

so your code will be

```
for($row = 0; $row < sizeof($arr);$row++){
 echo '<div class="img_container"><img src="images/'.$arr[$row]['isbn'].'.jpg" alt="Mountain View" ><br>'.$arr[$row]['title'].'<br/>by '.$arr[$row]['author'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="booktype" value="hardcover" >Hardcover: $'.$arr[$row]['hardcover'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="booktype" value="softcover" >Softcover: $'.$arr[$row]['softcover'].'<br/><input type="radio" name="booktype" value="e-book" >E-Book: $'.$arr[$row]['e-book'].'</div>';
}
```

and css

```
.img_container{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

i make this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t97ggmxy/) with dummy data in js as i can't do it with php

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as simple as this in your CSS:

```
.your-element img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Play around with the width setting so the images don't look squashed etc.

Comment: when I try this it is perfectly block with the words below it..but it's not displaying the images side by side...how can I fix this..

Answer (score 0):

small edit from @coderSte try

```
.your-element img {
display: inline-flex;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply this css rule to the img (or add a class to the imgs for example cimg)

```
img.cimg {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
}
```

I guess this should work and do the job you want to do.

Im updateing my answer to solve the issue:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwgdEK
Check this ... i guess this is what you are looking for.

You will have the change a bit the structure of your html aswell but that should solve your problems.

Comment: Hey I have tried this but when I view it the words are appearing on the side, how do I make the words appear directly below the image but at the same time make the pictures float